# Trigger events on input text before and after debounce

Tags: angular

Angular 8

The following code works well to trigger after 1s of typing:

Template:

```
<input [formControl]="nameControl">
```

TS

```
nameControl = new FormControl();
nameControlSub: Subscription;

...

this.nameControlSub = this.nameControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(debounceTime(1000), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(newValue => this.filterResults(newValue) );
```

In addition to the above, I want to trigger an event immediately upon typing. Essentially, my goal is to set `this.loading = true` as soon as the user starts typing, even though the debounce hasn't triggered yet. Then, once the debounce function finishes I will set `this.loading = false`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator for the same.

```
this.nameControlSub = this.nameControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    tap(()=> this.isLoading = true),
    debounceTime(1000), 
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe(newValue => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.filterResults(newValue)
    });
```